# Dell latitude E6230 motherboard

Tags: laptop, processor, motherboard

I have a dell latitude E6230 i5 laptop, which is recently do not start anymore, it was verified by a technician and he said that the motherboard is damaged, so I have to bay a motherboard from aliexpress. When I looked through the site, I have found two types of cards and I do not know how to verify which one to bay:

- The first one is :   Motherboard I5-33**20**M
- The second one is:   Motherboard I5-33**40**M
- And the last one is: Motherboard I5-33**80**M

I provide the links for each one below:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000034751897.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.65fd3a70FXEY9g&algo_pvid=2fa82fa5-b81a-477a-abcc-a0466a5d3317&algo_expid=2fa82fa5-b81a-477a-abcc-a0466a5d3317-4&btsid=708e4582-f87a-4e37-b329-af87e98b09b1&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5,searchweb201603_53

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32950340822.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.518e78b31AqNiQ&algo_pvid=2417d833-e5ec-4760-8a1c-00ccc477797d&algo_expid=2417d833-e5ec-4760-8a1c-00ccc477797d-9&btsid=39fa5f3a-e1f6-4e00-81e8-c61558238710&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5,searchweb201603_53

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32835849787.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.65fd3a70FXEY9g&algo_pvid=2fa82fa5-b81a-477a-abcc-a0466a5d3317&algo_expid=2fa82fa5-b81a-477a-abcc-a0466a5d3317-3&btsid=708e4582-f87a-4e37-b329-af87e98b09b1&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5,searchweb201603_53

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these three options is the CPU model, which is soldered to the board. So it depends entirely on your preference which CPU you want.
But judging by the current used prices for this particular laptop, I would seriously consider if buying a used motherboard and trying to fix the problem is worth it, compared to just buying a replacement.

Comment: So, witchever I buy it will operate properly in my laptop, because i  will buy it to replace and not to prepare the old one

Comment: Yes, either of these three options should work as a replacement motherboard in your laptop. Assuming it arrives in working order, and the transplant is successful. I don't understand what you mean by "and not to prepare the old one".

Comment: Please, these cards are  they New? Because in the site  they have writen ( item condition: used)

Comment: These are most likely used parts. Salvaged from laptops that had other defects, like broken screens etc